# React - can't read property "value" of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

While learning redux I have come to a standstill when trying to fire an action.  I am able to console log action.payload successfully, as well as {data} in the action so I suspect maybe it has something to do with local storage(?) but I really can't see what's wrong.  I am able to access everything from the database correctly in other areas of the app so I don't think there is any problem with the database.  Please let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Here is my reducer :

```
export const cartReducer = (state = { cartItems: [] }, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case CART_ADD_ITEM:
            const item = action.payload;
            console.log("a.p", action.payload);
            const existItem = state.cartItems.find(
                (x) => x.product === item.product
            );
            if (existItem) {
                return {
                    ...state,
                    cartItems: state.cartItems.map((x) =>
                        x.product === existItem.product ? item : x
                    ),
                };
            } else {
                return {
                    ...state,
                    cartItems: [...state.cartItems, item],
                };
            }
```

And here is my action :

```
export const addToCart = (id, qty) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${id}`);

    dispatch({
        type: CART_ADD_ITEM,
        payload: {
            product: data._id,
            name: data.name,
            image: data.image,
            price: data.price,
            countInStock: data.countInStock,
            qty,
        },
    });

    localStorage.setItem(
        "cartItems",
        JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cartItems)
    );
};
```

and store :

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import {
    productListReducer,
    productDetailsReducer,
} from "./reducers/productReducers";
import { cartReducer } from "./reducers/cartReducers";

const reducer = combineReducers({
    productList: productListReducer,
    productDetails: productDetailsReducer,
    cart: cartReducer,
});

const cartItemsFromStorage = localStorage.getItem("cartItems")
    ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartItems"))
    : [];

const initialState = {
    cart: { cartItems: cartItemsFromStorage },
};

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
    reducer,
    initialState,
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);
export default store;
```

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: If you are console logging in the reducer function then you successfully dispatched an action. Where in your snippet do you attempt to read a `value` property of an object? What/where is the error pointing to? Is there a stacktrace you can include?

Comment: So the value that is being read is "product", I kept it sort of universal in the title by saying "value" but I realise now that is confusing, sorry. The error points to line  6 ```const existItem = state.cartItems.find```in the reducer.  If the action is being dispatched should it come up in the redux devtools?

Comment: Yes, I believe it will show in the redux-devtool. Does `console.log("a.p", action.payload);` or `console.log("a.p", item);` also log the expected payload object and match what is seen in the devtool?

Comment: These both log the expected payload but I can't see CART_ADD_ITEM in the redux devtools unfortunately.

Comment: Are there any other reducers that also handle that `CART_ADD_ITEM` action? I suspect something is mutating that action's `payload` object if you are able to log the correct value and then a couple lines later in a callback it becomes undefined. Have you tried removing the localStorage code (*just to help simplify code*)?

Comment: Let's work backwards.  You cannot read `.product` of `undefined` in this line `x.product === item.product` -- so either `x` or `item` is `undefined`, but I'm not sure which.  You are saying that the `payload` looks correct when you log it so it's got be the `x`.  Somehow you are winding up with one or more `undefined` items in your `state.cartItems` array.  Add another `console.log(state.cartItems)` -- are you seeing any undefined?

Comment: Unrelated to the issue, but the `addToCart` action creator is definitely not the right place to be updating `localStorage`.  You are going to get the value from before this action was dispatched when you do `JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cartItems)`